# Why does a subquery cause a scan when a static list does not?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got a query containing a subquery which always causes a SCAN of a very large table resulting in poor query times.

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT PersonId 
  FROM person 
 WHERE PersonId IN (
                    SELECT PersonId 
                      FROM relationship 
                     WHERE RelatedToPersonId = 12270351721
                   );
```

The query plan is reported as:

```
SCAN TABLE person (~100000 rows)
EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
SEARCH TABLE relationship USING INDEX relationship_RelatedToPersonId_IDX (RelatedToPersonId=?) (~10 rows)
```

The same query with a static list (equivalent to the results of the subquery):

```
SELECT PersonId 
  FROM person 
 WHERE PersonId IN (12270351727,12270351730,12270367969,12387741400);
```

And the query plan for that:

```
SEARCH TABLE person USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_person_1 (PersonId=?) (~5 rows)
EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
```

Why would the first query prompt a scan if the second does not?

Comment: If the dataset from your subquery is small then a transient table may work.  Something like:
Select Personid From (SELECT PersonId FROM relationship WHERE RelatedToPersonId=12270351721);

Comment: I tried a transient table and it still produced a scan.

Comment: Can a `PersonId` exist in `relationship` if there isn't a row in `person`? If not, doesn't the subquery (possibly with a `distinct`) satisfy the entire query?

Comment: This is a contrived query to demonstrate the problem. The real query performs a more complex subquery and returns other columns from person but displays the same inefficient behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Probably unmatched datatypes.  Does person.PersonId and relationship.PersonId have the same data definition.

Answer (score 2):

The table has to be scanned because you're including another field (RelatedToPersonId) in the WHERE clause of your subquery.  The list of PersonIDs can go directly to the index.

Comment: RelatedToPersonId is in the relationship table. Why would that cause a scan of the person table? Shouldn't that subquery execute independently, produce it's result list and then behave the same as the query with the static list of values? If you look at the query plan for the that query, the subquery portion is actually hitting the index.

Comment: The SQLite optimizer should definitely be able to know that the subquery can use an index and make sure to execute it first and then restrict the rows from the person table to just that result set.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce. I executed the following statements on a fresh SQLite version 3.7.8 install:

```
create table person (id int not null primary key, name varchar(20));
insert into person values (1, 'a');
insert into person select id + 1, name || 'b' from person;
insert into person select id + 2, name || 'c' from person;
insert into person select id + 4, name || 'd' from person;
insert into person select id + 8, name || 'e' from person;
insert into person select id + 16, name || 'f' from person;
insert into person select id + 32, name || 'g' from person;
insert into person select id + 64, name || 'h' from person;
insert into person select id + 128, name || 'i' from person;
insert into person select id + 256, name || 'j' from person;
insert into person select id + 512, name || 'k' from person;
insert into person select id + 512, name || 'l' from person;
insert into person select id + 1024, name || 'l' from person;
insert into person select id + 2048, name || 'm' from person;
insert into person select id + 4096, name || 'n' from person;
insert into person select id + 8192, name || 'o' from person;
insert into person select id + 16384, name || 'p' from person;
insert into person select id + 32768, name || 'q' from person;
insert into person select id + 65536, name || 'r' from person;
select count(*) from person;

create table relation (id int, related int);
insert into relation select id, id + 1 from person;
insert into relation select id, id + 2 from person;
insert into relation select id, id + 3 from person;
insert into relation select id, id + 4 from person;
insert into relation select id, id + 5 from person;
insert into relation select id, id + 6 from person;
insert into relation select id, id + 7 from person;
insert into relation select id, id + 8 from person;
insert into relation select id, id + 9 from person;
insert into relation select id, id + 10 from person;
delete from relation where related not in (select id from person);

create index relatedToPerson on relation(related);
explain query plan select id from person 
    where id in (select id from relation where related = 2345);
```

The results for the query plan statement:

```
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE person USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_person_1 (id=?)(~25 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE relation USING INDEX relatedToPerson (related=?) (~10 rows)
```

Why doesn't it work for you? The reasons I can think of:

- your table relationship doesn't contain the column PersonId (please
  verify)
- you are using another version of SQLite
- you have other constraints, for example unique indexes.

Can you run the script above and verify if you get the same results I got?

Comment: I've been too busy this week to get to this and I'm going out of town tomorrow, so I may not be able to give further time to this for a few more days. But I don't want to waste the bounty so I'm awarding it to you for the effort you've put in. If your example truly causes no scan then that will give me a good place to start from when trying to understand why mine doesn't work the same.

Comment: Good luck. Please post your results here. I'm curious what the difference is.

Comment: Mismatched data types (text vs integer)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why there is a table scan. But there is no need to use a subselect here: You could also use a join:

```
SELECT person.PersonId 
  FROM person JOIN relationship ON person.PersonId = relationship.PersonId
 WHERE RelatedToPersonId = 12270351721;
```

Not sure if sqlite supports this JOIN syntax, but this could also be re-written using FROM and WHERE:

```
SELECT person.PersonId 
  FROM person, relationship 
 WHERE person.PersonId = relationship.PersonId
   AND RelatedToPersonId = 12270351721;
```

And, maybe this is more what the optimizer is tuned for.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments above, this is a contrived query that demonstrates a very simple case of an unexpected scan. The "real life" query is substantially more complex but boils down to the same situation - a subquery that produces a short list which produces a scan while putting the same values in a static list does not cause the scan.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
SELECT PersonId 
  FROM person 
 WHERE PersonId IN (12270351727,12270351730,12270367969,12387741400);
```

is merely syntactic sugar for this:

```
SELECT PersonId 
  FROM person 
 WHERE (
        PersonId = 12270351727
        OR PersonId = 12270351730
        OR PersonId = 12270367969
        OR PersonId = 12387741400
       );
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain why a scan is necessary when a subquery is employed or, more importantly, how to avoid that scan. It just seems that the SQLite query optimizer is not producing an optimal query plan in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It cause full scan because sub-query executed for each row in `person`. Sub-queries do not "cache" their result set to be converted into `IN`.

Hope it helps.